# Notifying team members of missed work for bachelor party

Tags: professionalism, ethics, time-off

I will be a groomsman in an upcoming wedding. The bachelor party was scheduled on a Thursday morning, and it's multiple hours away from where I live/work, so attending means missing all day Thursday.

Is it unprofessional to notify my boss and coworkers of my absence, saying that I need to attend a bachelor party? It seems like I'm shirking on work in order to merely relax/party.

Is it dishonest to just say I'm "out of the office helping with wedding prep"?

Comment: What's your employment situation? Do you have a time off policy at your employer? Most full time employment includes PTO (personal time off) which is designed for reasons like this. It's perfectly normal to take the time at-will and not explain the specific reason, or tell anyone what you're doing while off.

Comment: I'm a new hire, and my paid time off is not yet available (it will kick in after 6 mos). At my workplace we customarily put "Out of Office - <reason>" as the subject line of the Outlook appointment notification sent to team members.

Comment: Do you get PTO days? Do you get vacation time? If so, schedule a PTO or vacation day. You don't need to explain why.

Comment: Yes, policy allows me to take time off and make it up beforehand/later. My question is just about apearances.

Comment: Josh, can you just say "personal day"?  So "out of office - personal day".  Another one is "Out of office - family event".  That's the usual thing you say for a wedding.  (Even if it's not literally "your" family, weddings are "family events" (like a "family movie") so that's the usual thing to write in such a form.  Nobody wants to know the details of whether it's a funeral, wedding, or whatever. (Nobody cares, nobody wants that much detail - "family event" is the catch-all for that category).  Enjoy!

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but your personal life belongs to you and is your private business. If the policy allows you to take the time off then you don't need to excuse, explain, quantify, qualify, justify, or apologize for taking the time off.

Comment: @joeqwerty - my sense is the OP very simply wants to know what is best to write in the slot: "Out of Office - <reason>".  (It's just "family event" for funerals, weddings, etc.)

Comment: Why does the OP need to give a reason at all? The policy allows the time off. He doesn't need to say why, and frankly, it isn't anyone's business. I don't tell people WHY I'm taking time off. If policy allows me to take time off then I say "I'm taking time off". I set my out of office message to say "I'm currently out of the office. If you need immediate assistance please contact...". Why do people feel that they need to explain the reason or justify it?

Comment: @joe - *"At my workplace we customarily put "Out of Office - <reason>" as the subject line of the Outlook appointment notification sent to team members."*  That seems reasonable to me.  For example:  say one of the guys says to me "I'm taking the day off tomorrow to relax" I know that (in that example) if there's an astonishing opportunity to meet Bill Gates or something, of course I'd contact him anyway even though it's a day off; but if the person's like "getting married" or simply overseas, or whatever, it's convenient to know that.  On most teams I think.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My point is that I don't feel the need to justify or give the reason when I take time off. It may be customary, and that's fine, but I don't see the necessity of it. It's as if people need to justify the fact that they have a life outside of work.

Comment: At the same time, I COMPLETELY agree with you in general terms that when you take time off you owe nobody any explanation whatsoever - worker's rights!  (I guess I interpret the question as nothing more than "What's the best word for this slot - - - when you'e a groomsman?")  (After all, folks, may, say happen to ask where he was to make conversation. You don't want to reply *me and the mates were vomiting with strippers all day!* but rather "family event!"  :)  )

Comment: @joeqwerty You should know that anal people that aren't flexible enough to fit in or follow social etiquette because "mah rights", don't get employed long.  Just a word of advice.

Comment: I get your point... my point is that an employee doesn't need to justify or explain their personal life to their employer. They don't need to make a fuss about it, just say "I'm taking personal time". Anything more is unnecessary. If an employer insists on knowing why then they've breached a line that shouldn't be breached. My employer employees me, that doesn't give them the leeway to have any insight or input into my personal life.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable to use leave time to attend a bachelor party. It's also perfectly acceptable to use it to go to a wedding, go to a beach resort, attend a comic book convention, go backpacking, visit your parents, stay at home and do nothing, or whatever you feel like doing. The point of vacation time is that you can do whatever you want, and you aren't "shirking" at all.

You aren't required to tell your coworkers exactly what you did if you don't want to either, but no one should look down on you attending a bachelor party. Though depending on what exactly happens at this bachelor party, make sure whatever stories you tell afterwards are work-appropriate.

**Update to address comments:**

> I'm a new hire, and my paid time off is not yet available (it will kick in after 6 mos). At my workplace we customarily put "Out of Office - " as the subject line of the Outlook appointment notification sent to team members. [...] Yes, policy allows me to take time off and make it up beforehand/later. My question is just about apearances.

If you don't have PTO available to you yet, then how you get time off approved is dependent on the system at your work (and it sounds like you have that part figured out already). That doesn't change the fact that the bachelor party qualifies as vacation, and that specific activity shouldn't change how your time off is perceived.

For your Out-of-office message, I would probably just say "Vacation". This just says that you are not at work and discourages people from calling you, without actually saying precisely what you are doing and where you are. I would also do that regardless of what my vacation activity was, mainly because I value privacy and don't feel the need to broadcast to everyone what my vacation activities are. I'm happy to tell my coworkers about my vacations, but Carol from Accounting who I've never spoken to doesn't need to know those details of my personal life.

Now, there is the question of how taking vacation time early in your job would be perceived, regardless of where you are going. I would say that would depend a lot on your company culture and the personality of your boss. If they are willing to approve a PTO "loan" for you for a leisure trip, then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: However, it's not leave time.  "I'm a new hire, and my paid time off is not yet available".  Taking time off (without pay) when you're very new is ..  well, you're just courteous about it.

Comment: @Fattie Thanks, that wasn't there when I answered. I edited my answer to address the OP's comments.

Comment: In my experience, how you get time off approved is dependent on the system at your work, regardless of whether or not you have PTO available (although not having PTO might make it a bit different / more effort / less likely to be approved). Although the system at one's work may involve being able to take your PTO whenever you want.

Comment: @DavidK right, it's confusing - and common - when issues "come to light" like that on this site  :/

Answer (score 5):

I guess I'll put in an answer:

To the specific question:

> Is it ok to just say I'm "out of the office helping with wedding prep"?

**Yes**.

It is absolutely OK to **"generalize" your explanations** of why you're out of the office on any personal day.

This is a desirable and good thing - it is professional to ***not*** go in to detail.

Examples,

- You're under investigation by the Feds.  "Doing some paperwork."
- Funeral for a beloved cat.  "Had to attend to some family matters."
- Breast (or .. whatever) enlargement operation.  "Some medical appointments."

Again **yes** it's absolutely correct and good to describe "mental bachelor party" as "wedding prep".

(In fact, I recommend just "family event".  Anything vaguely related to weddings, births, deaths is just "family event.")

> "Out of Office - $reason$"

"Out of Office, family event"

or

"Out of Office, wedding"

Don't forget too, you can always just say "personal day".  But for me "personal day" is a bit mysterious, simply write "family event" which is totally innocuous.  Bottoms up!

Answer (score 0):

> I will be a groomsman in an upcoming wedding. The bachelor party was
>   scheduled on a Thursday morning, and it's multiple hours away from
>   where I live/work, so attending means missing all day Thursday.
>
> Is it unprofessional to notify my boss and coworkers of my absence,
>   saying that I need to attend a bachelor party? It seems like I'm
>   shirking on work in order to merely relax/party.
>
> Is it dishonest to just say I'm "out of the office helping with
>   wedding prep"?

Often a good way to answer "is this dishonest?" questions is to ask yourself: if the other party discovered the truth, would *they* feel that I had behaved honestly?

For instance, suppose that one of the other groomsmen posts photos of the party on Facebook, and one of your co-workers comes across those photos and recognises you. Would they feel that you'd given them a honest explanation of what you were doing, or would they feel that you'd misled them? I don't know your co-workers or your workplace culture, so I can't answer that, but hopefully you can.

Beyond that, I agree with other posters - keep it general. If it were me, I'd probably just say "attending a friend's wedding"; for me that feels a bit more honest, but your mileage (and your co-workers') may vary.